# Find the intersection of all combination of list of list

Tags: r, tidyverse, combinations, intersect, ggalluvial

My ultimate goal is to have alluvial plots in `R`. However, my data is big and is not stored in a way that can be used for direct input, I have:

1. 4 groups (they will be axes of the alluvial plot)
2. In each of these groups consist of a list of a list of vector

My thought is to use `length(intersect())` to get the frequency of each combination of the list of list of vectors.

To get the combination of the list of list, I used `cross()` from the `purrr`. I am not sure if this is the right way to get this combination matrix, and I am open to other methods. Similarly, I am open to other pipelines that can accomplish the goal. The main reason is that I am stuck at this point and cannot find a good way to find the intersection of the list of list of vectors.

Below is a toy dataset and the expected output I would like to get (I type the result manually):

```
library(tidyverse)
group1 <- list(module1 = c("test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"),
               module2 = c("test7", "test8", "test9", "test10"),
               module3 = c("test11", "test12", "test13"))

group2 <- list(module1 = c("test3", "test4", "test5", "test7", "test8"),
               module2 = c("test1", "test12", "test13"),
               module3 = c("test2", "test6", "test11"))

group3 <- list(module1 = c("test3", "test5", "test6", "test8"),
               module2 = c("test1", "test7", "test9", "test10"),
               module3 = c("test13", "test14", "test15"))

list_combination <- list(group1 = names(group1), group2 = names(group2), group3 = names(group3)) %>% 
  cross() %>% 
  bind_rows()

expected_result_intersect <- list_combination %>%  #below are the results
  mutate(intersect_result = list(
    c("test3", "test5"), #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module1))
    c("test8"), #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module1))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module1))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module1))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module1))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module1))
    c("test6"), #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module1))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module1))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module1))
    c("test5"), #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module2))
    c("test7"), #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module2))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module2))
    c("test1"), #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module2))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module2))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module2))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module2))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module2))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module2))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module3))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module3))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module1, group3_module3))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module3))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module3))
    c("test13"), #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module2, group3_module3))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module1, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module3))
    NULL, #intersect(group1_module2, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module3))
    NULL #intersect(group1_module3, intersect(group2_module3, group3_module3))
    ))

expected_result_counts <- expected_result_intersect %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Freq = length(intersect_result))


library(ggalluvial)
ggplot(expected_result_counts,
       aes(y = Freq, axis1 = group1, axis2 = group2)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = group3), width = 1/12) +
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Group1", "Group2"), expand = c(.05, .05)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = "Set1") +
  ggtitle("test plot")
```

Something to note:

- I am not trying to get any combination within the group, i.e. I do
  not need `intersect(group1_module1, group1_module2)` as the character
  vectors within the group are having distinct elements.
- In the real dataset, I have over 50 modules per group. Therefore, it would be great if the proposed method is computation/RAM efficient.

I am open to other languages to process the data but prefer using R to plot the graph as I am more familiar with `ggplot`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(cross(lst(group1, group2, group3)), ~reduce(.x, intersect))
```

is what you are looking for

```
my_list <- lst(group1, group2, group3)

list_combination%>%
  mutate(result = map(cross(my_list),~reduce(.x,intersect)))

# A tibble: 27 × 4
   group1  group2  group3  result   
   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <list>   
 1 module1 module1 module1 <chr [2]>
 2 module2 module1 module1 <chr [1]>
 3 module3 module1 module1 <chr [0]>
 4 module1 module2 module1 <chr [0]>
 5 module2 module2 module1 <chr [0]>
 6 module3 module2 module1 <chr [0]>
 7 module1 module3 module1 <chr [1]>
 8 module2 module3 module1 <chr [0]>
 9 module3 module3 module1 <chr [0]>
10 module1 module1 module2 <chr [0]>
# … with 17 more rows
```

---

In base R:

```
 apply(expand.grid(my_list),1, Reduce,f=intersect)
```